# How to sort bye value and only return items above a certain value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to sort an array of objects, whose items in the sort method went through a function that makes them return a value, and then return the objects' items whose value is above a certain number.

I've tried this:

```
sortedObject(){
  return this.arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) =>
    (this.formatValue(b) > 0.7) - (this.formatValue(a) > 0.7)
  )
}
```

`this.formatValue` gets an item and through a series of calculations from the object properties returns a value between 0 and 1. I want the sorting to only return items whose value is above 0.7 and put them sorted in that `sortedObject` computed property. An item with value below 0.7 would not be included in the `sortedObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` function returns an array of the same length as the original array. So, you can't do this in a single call. You need to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this before calling `sort`.

```
sortedObject() {
  return this.arrayOfObjects
             .filter(a => this.formatValue(a) > 0.7)
             .sort((a, b) => this.formatValue(b) - this.formatValue(a))
}
```

If `formatValue()` is an expensive operation and you want to call it only once per object, then you can `map` it to a new Array before doing `filter`. But, this returns an array of objects with an additional property `formatValue`

```
sortedObject() {
  return this.arrayOfObjects
    .map(a => ({ formatValue: this.formatValue(a), ...a}))
    .filter(a => a.formatValue > 0.7)
    .sort((a, b) => b.formatValue - a.formatValue)
}
```

Another option is to use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) property inside each object and call the `formatValue()` function in it.

Answer (score 2):

Than it's not just sorting, you need to first filter items with < 0.7, then sort the rest:

I would first map only the computed values, then filter them and then sort them:

```
sortedObject(){
  return this.arrayOfObjects.map(a => this.formatValue(a))
                            .filter(a => a > 0.7)
                            .sort((a, b) => b - a)
}
```

#### Edit

```
sortedObject(){
  return this.arrayOfObjects.filter(a => this.formatValue(a) > 0.7)
                            .sort(
                              (a, b) =>
                                this.formatValue(b) - this.formatValue(a)
                            )
}
```

Comment: I feel slightly dumb for not having tried a filter before sorting. Thanks

Comment: @Doge Note: `sortedObject` returns an array of numbers which `formatValue` is returning. Not a portion of the original array.

Comment: @adiga you are right, let's say what Doge says about it and, in case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @adiga and @0xc14m1z for pointing that out. I would like to return the objects sorted and filtered, not just the `formatValue` numbers

Comment: My last edit should return the original items, but filtered of those that formatted are less than 0.7 and with their formatted values sorted.

Answer (score 1):

user filter pipe here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
sortedObject(){
  return this.arrayOfObjects
..filter(a=> a > 0.7);
.sort((a, b) =>
    (this.formatValue(b) > 0.7) - (this.formatValue(a) > 0.7)
  )
}
```